# Error Inflating for Background Drawables for marshmallow

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This Code is working fine with `Lollipop` bellow. But for `Marshmallow`, I am getting Inflating Error because of the

```
android:background="@drawable/border_box_gray"
```

-

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/border_box_gray"

        android:padding="10dp"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/race_list_linearlayout">
```

This is the border_box_ray xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#202020" />
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#9b9b9b"/>
</shape>
```

I don't have `app:srcCompat` for `Gradle`. But I am not sure how to work around this issue.

Comment: what is divider drawable?

Comment: show `@drawable/divider`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to put a spacing before `android:shape`

Comment: its there, android:shape="rectangle"

Comment: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle". <-- This line, before android:shape="rectangle" must have a spacing. Right now, you joint everything in one sentence.

Comment: it is only on this Stackoverflow editor, it is separated on xml